Integer solutions for multivariate polynomial systems: Is there an analogous criterion based on Smith normal form? (and Moment matrices)
I am looking for the analogous lemma for multivariate polynomials with integer coefficients:
(taken from Applications of polynomial Smith normal form calculations)
Lemma 5
Consider the linear system $Ax=b$, the following statements are equivalent:
(i) $Ax=b$ has an integer solution
(ii) $t_i$ divides $a_i$ ($i=1,...r$) and $a_{r+1}=...=a_m=0$
(iii) $S^*(A)=S^*(A|b)$
with $S^*(A)=diag(t_1,...,t_r)$ the nonsingular part of the Smith normal form.
My question will be elaborated from now on:
The basic idea of the Moment Method (The approach of moments for polynomial equations) is to linearize the system of polynomial equations by introducing variables $y=(y_{\alpha})$ for the monomials $x^{\alpha}$
Is there a similar lemma for polynomial systems with integer coefficients based on Moment Matrices (Macaulay-like matrices)?:
$$[x]_s[x]_s^T=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}1 & x_1 & x_2 & x_1^2 & \ldots \\ x_1 & x_1^2 & x_1 x_2 & x_1^3 & \ldots \\ x_2 & x_1 x_2 & x_2^2 & x_1^2 x_2 & \ldots \\ x_1^2 & x_1^3 & x_1^2 x_2 & x_1^4 & \ldots \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots\end{array}\right) \rightsquigarrow M_s(y)\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}1 & y_{10} & y_{01} & y_{20} & \ldots \\ y_{10} & y_{20} & y_{11} & y_{30} & \ldots \\ y_{01} & y_{11} & y_{02} & y_{21} & \ldots \\ y_{20} & y_{30} & y_{21} & y_{40} & \ldots \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots\end{array}\right)$$.
